# Java Calendar Reminder

Tags: java, eclipse

So my question is this:

How can i make a calendar or task reminder in java? I was looking up the net for a whole week now and could not figure out how exactly to do this.

So i want to make my program to do this:

1. The user inputs a string
2. Then to this string we add a date and time reminder so it can pop up on a specific date with a text plus the string
3. Then this whole string and date is stored in a DB or a file, it so we can delete it or modify it with new date and time or whatsoever.

I have worked things out to input a string and save it to DB, but i cannot figure out how to set a reminder for 2 pt. Please give me an advice how to do it. I will be verry grateful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some Cron (Scheduler) like:

- [Quartz Job Scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/overview) library
- [Spring TaskScheduler, <task:scheduled-tasks>](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html)
- [Executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html) bundled with Java. Specifically a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) implemented in the [`ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html)
  class.